# Div not showing in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo '<div id="signin-box"> ' . wp_login_form() . ' </div>';
} else {
    echo 'hi';
}
?>
```

Is what I've got. The login form is working, but it is not being wrapped in the div. Without the else/if statement, it works.

Comment: So you want to output the login form for users that are logged in?

Comment: Reversed it for ease of viewing changes (since I'm logged in, it was inconvenient to log out/log in every time I wanted to see what was happening)

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in states it returns true if logged in and false if not.

You are probably looking for:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    echo '<div id="signin-box">' . wp_login_form(array('echo' => false)) . '</div>';
}else{
    echo 'hi';
}
```

Adding `!` inverses `true` to `false` so if user is not logged in show login form else say hi. Also adding `array('echo' => false)` will give a return instead of echoing, removing `array('echo' => false)` you'll have to put `wp_login_form()` on its own line without a echo:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    echo '<div id="signin-box">';
    wp_login_form();
    echo '</div>';
}else{
    echo 'hi';
}
```

Comment: It was reversed just to be simpler on my end for the time being. Actual is <?php
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
     global $current_user;
         get_currentuserinfo();
         echo 'Thanks for logging in, ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
  } else {
     echo '<div id="signin-box"> '.wp_login_form().' </div>';
  }
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
<?php

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    ?>
    <div id="signin-box">
    <?= wp_login_form(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
} else {
    echo 'hi';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add this code it seems work like this please add this code and check it.

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
    <div id="signin-box" class="test"><?php wp_login_form()?> </div>
<?php } else { 
    echo 'hi';
}
?>
```

In your code "echo" is not working in login form ..

Comment: You have to close php tag after if condition . And then start it after div is close .